# uninstall and reinstall to 13.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, 13.10, software-uninstall

As stated before I'm a complete novice with ubuntu and now I'm in a terrible bind. The most efficient and quickest way  see to fix nut issue is to delete and reinstall to the latest upgrade. How do i go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what your asking.. but the quickest way to install a fresh 13.10 install is to download the iso from http://www.ubuntu.com/download burn it to a DVD and go from there.

Comment: I recently upgraded from 12.04 LTS to 12.10. Its not functioning, I'm sure I did something wrong. So I want to remove ubuntu 12.10 and install 13.10.

Comment: "removing" 12.10 is not going to be possible now. Use your backup (you did do a backup didn't you) of your dot files and home directory to re-configure the system after doing a new install of 13.10 from the iso image as suggested above.